# objectcontext vs datacontext

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, ria

i'm just new in developping silverlight, and i created a linq to sql connection and a service domain class. I want to get data from 2 tables which have a 1 to many relation into a datagridview. To do this i need to state include commands in my metadata and service domain class , but to do this i need to have an objectcontext instead of a datacontext(that i'm currently having ) can someone help me with this matter so i can use the include statement to get querys for my detail-grid

edit:

I've done what u said added the

```
"<IncludeAttribute()> _"
Public Property SubgroepIndustries As EntitySet(Of SubgroepIndustrie)
```

but i get this error message:
Error   1   'Include' is not a member of 'System.Data.Linq.Table(Of ILA4.HoofdgroepIndustrie')
edit 2:
 when i try to use the include in my domain service class not the metadata so

```
Return Me.DataContext.HoofdgroepIndustries.Include("SubgroepIndustries")
```

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

`ObjectContext` is a class that is generated inside the generated `DomainService` class that you made.

Just do a `this.ObjectContext` in the `DomainService` class you made and you should have access to the class you are looking for.

I have assumed here that you are using RIA services and your `DomainService MetaData` class is tagged with `[Include]` attributes. Otherwise doing `this.ObjectContext.SomeEntity.Include("ChildEntity")` will not work out.

Edit:

Add `<IncludeAttribute()> _` to `Public Property SubgroepIndustries As EntitySet(Of SubgroepIndustrie)` in your .metadata.vb

As for `ObjectContext`, looking at your code you don't need `ObjectContext` I think. Use `DataContext` instead.

so for example:

```
Public Function GetHoofdgroepIndustries() As IQueryable(Of HoofdgroepIndustrie)
    Return Me.DataContext.HoofdgroepIndustries.Include("SubgroepIndustries")
End Function
```

is how you will do it.

Edit 2: You need `Imports System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server` for `<IncludeAttribute()>`

Comment: so i need to include first in my metadata before i can use it in my domain service class?Could u give me an example of the include for a metadata in vb ?like i got a table headindustry and a table subindustry , each headindustry has multiple subsindustry but each subindustry only has 1 headindustry

Comment: Give me a bit and I'll mash up an example in VB. Been a while since I coded in VB. Would help if you could share part of your DomainService Declaration and the associated .metadata.vb class so I could tell you exactly where to put the attribute.

Comment: perfect :) I was just deciphering your earlier comment in vb lol. Adding code to my post

Comment: No problem. I ran into same dead-ends two months back when I started on this path. Happy to help :)

Comment: correction: I think its not an imports error. I think it's to do with DomainService side .Include() ?

Comment: Seems like you don't get the same 'Include' method when you use `LinqToSQL` to generate `DomainService`. I'm used to working with `EDM` so this is now a head-scratching moment :) I'll do quick search on internet to see how to take this forward.

Comment: Its a bit confusing at first but yes, I tried both approaches and I prefer EDM over Linq2SQL now. Mostly because most of the examples on internet deal with EDM and it seems far more straight forward to me. Is it an option to convert to EDM? If so, I'd definitely go for it.

Comment: wish we could join in a chat room. this answer is turning into a chat :) I know about Lazy Loading but lazy coding? -- if you meant lazy loading, it is a great feature. It basically aggregates all your queries to run as one big merged / optimised query rather than querying over and over (by delaying the actual execution until the results are actually needed to go forward in code)

Comment: I just realised.. Do you have *RIA Toolkit* installed even? I'm using _RIA Services SP1_ + _RIA Services Toolkit for SP1_ and I have a `DataContext` in generated `DomainService` generated from `LinqToSQL Classes`  (LinqToSQL Classes DomainService exists only in RIA Toolkit)